# Titanium Webview Facebook Login broken on Android

Tags: android, wordpress, facebook, webview, titanium

I'm currently using a simple webview in my titanium app.
The webview points to a remote location which has a facebook login button.

The facebook login simply redirects to the facebook login page if you are not all ready logged in.

This button is located on a wordpress custom template file using a:

do_shortcode("[wordpress_social_login]");

When I go to login on my android physical device (Nexus 4), I get this page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pncpL.png
I also tested on a variety of Samsung Galaxy devices, same output.

The page is extremely broken, can't even click on any possible text fields.
The login however does not look messed up on:
- Emulators
- Browsers

I have absolutely no control of the stylings of this page as it is made by Facebook.

How do I fix this?

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="win" fullscreen="true" backgroundColor="white" layout="vertical" title="My Test Site">
        <ActionBar id="action_bar" title="Action Bar" />
        <View id="view_webview" width="100%" height="90%">
            <WebView id="webview" width="100%" height="100%" url="http://192.168.0.40" />
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, using some JavaScript in the WebViewClient seems to the trick for now:

put it inside of

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
```

...

```
String script = "javascript:"
    + "  try{ var divs = document.querySelectorAll('._4g34'); for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) { divs[i].style.width='100%'; } }catch(e){}";

// run script
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    view.loadUrl(script);
} else {
    view.evaluateJavascript(script, null);
}
```